# Jquery click not working first time when inputs are in focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now I have an `input` when typing in the input it automatically displays a list based on query.

When the 'Favourite' star icon is clicked I want to call some function. Here the problem is when the input is in focus. The first click is not working when input is still in focus. The second time the function is called.

How do I avoid this and make the click work first time even though input is in focus?

```js
let name = 'foo';

jQuery($ => {
  $("#search-input").on("change keydown paste input", function() {
    if (this.value == "") {
      return true;
    }

    // some filter function on object to loop and display below list.
    $(".search-result").append("<li class='searchitem'>" + name + " <i class='favourite far fa-star'></i></li>");
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".favourite", function() {
    alert("hi");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<input type="text" id="search-input" />
<ul class="search-result">

</ul>
```

Comment: I placed your code in an executable snippet where you can see the code works correctly - the `alert()` appears on the first click. If it's not working in your local version there must be an issue caused by some other JS in your page, which you've not included in the question. Please edit the question to show a demo of the issue

Comment: There are lots of code , is there any other way to find it whats causing this issue.. can this be due to CSS too ?

Comment: It's possible that it's CSS related (if using `pointer-events: none` on an overlaid element, for example), but unlikely.

Comment: You may have something cancelling the click event (eg `return false`) before it gets to your delegated event handler.